# Where can I find the JSapar updated source code and active forum?

Tags: java, csv, parsing, text-files, jsapar

Where can I find the JSapar's updated source code (1.5.x)?
Where can I find an active forum about that library? That library still active?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The home page of the JSaPar project has now moved to https://org-tigris-jsapar.github.io/jsapar/

The sourcecode has moved to https://github.com/org-tigris-jsapar/jsapar where you also can report issues etc.

I am afraid that there is not that much of an active forum for the library but please continue to use StackOverflow. Just add the tag **jsapar**. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the information @stenix
I found that SVN URL, but I didn't see the tag "jasapar-1.5" because it is just a bit different than the other tags.

I will post my questions at the forum.

Obs.: Can you create the jsapar tag? I really can't do this due my reputation :/

Thank you!

Comment: As of version 1.5.0 I use Maven to build and publish releases instead of my home-made Ant-script. That is why the tag looks a bit different.

As I mentioned, I don't have enough reputations either to create tags in StackOverflow :(. As soon as I reach the correct level I will create the discussion tag.